# Node.js Background Application for Windows 10 Core

Tags: node.js, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

He guys,
We are currently stuck on some fundamentals. We have a simple Webview App as a frontend on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 Core as a UWP app.
But we also need a background task/app to manage a device that is connected via usb. The program we have is written in Nodejs and the question is if there is ANY way to port this to Windows 10 Core. Every Idea welcome.
Usually we launch and set up the Application in pm2.

Comment: Hi NotAdrian, Node.js cannot be used in UWP apps since version 17686. Older samples in these languages may no longer function correctly. Microsoft is considering alternatives for a future release. See [Release Notes for Build 17686](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/insider/17686#known-issues-in-this-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer for Node.js is NO.

The workaround is using background task/app in UWP using other languages:[C#, C++, jvascript
and Visual Basic.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore#programming-languages)

More reference:

"[Developing Background Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications)"

"[Support your app with background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks)"